# I have some problems with installing Python (there's no IDLE) - Windows 10 64bit

Tags: installation

I installed (I mean wanted to install) Python, but I got this message:

[image]

And I clicked OK, and the Python was installed. But there’s no IDLE, and there’s no “Edit with IDLE” option. Python is not on the list of the programs, and I can’t uninstall it. What can I do to have IDLE?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install python version 3.9.0

Use below link
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.0/python-3.9.0-amd64.exe